# TinyMCE cannot be resolved error on JSP

Tags: jsp, tinymce

Environment: RAD IDE, JSP, tinyMCE.
I am trying to build a rich text editor using tinyMCE and JSP.
Steps:

1. I downloaded the TinyMCE 3.4.3 package (comment -production usage) from http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/download.php
2. unzipped the package and placed the "tinymce" folder under WebContent folder.
3. Modified the jsp  code with javascript code as mentioned

Code:

```
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="insertYourPath/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    tinyMCE.init({ 
      mode : "textareas", 
      theme : "simple"   //(n.b. no trailing comma, this will be critical as you experiment later) 
    }); 
  </script> 
</head>
```

Issue: The JSP shows an error that tinyMCE is not resolvable and I don't see the editor being rendered. I added a check for `tinymce.editors.length > 0` also and it also returned the same result.
Any suggestions why `tinyMCE.init` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript URL is invalid.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="insertYourPath/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

It says `insertYourPath` which is clearly an example path. It seems that you did not take this into account and edited it accordingly.

When the JSP is located in webcontent root, just remove it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Or when you don't want to worry about relative URLs because your JSPs can be in any folder or being forwarded by a servlet according the MVC ideology, then include the context path dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep got it working...even though the jsp still shows a red with "tinyMCE.init" not reslovable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Helps well to get editor coming up with all the required fields. Its just need to turn off the jsp validator if do not want to see red with "tinyMCE.init". Thanks.